# Image not renders first time only in custom markerInfoWindow on google maps SWIFT iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using google maps and showing custom annotation view. For custom view i am using this google maps function:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let index:Int! = Int(marker.accessibilityLabel!)
        let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindowGoogleMap
        customInfoWindow.labelFoodName.text = self.mapData?.details?[index].title ?? ""
        customInfoWindow.labelOwnerName.text = self.mapData?.details?[index].name ?? ""
        customInfoWindow.labelTimePosted.text = self.mapData?.details?[index].posted ?? ""
        customInfoWindow.labelOwnerNumber.text = self.mapData?.details?[index].phone ?? ""
        customInfoWindow.labelOwnerEmail.text = self.mapData?.details?[index].email ?? ""
        self.setImageWithUrl(imageUrl: self.mapData?.details?[index].image ?? "", imageView: customInfoWindow.imageViewItem)
        return customInfoWindow
    }
```

Everything works fine but the image view is not loading image for the first time only. When i click pin again, then it loads instantly. What can be the issue?

Comment: i have same issues please tell me how can you solved it??

Comment: @hemant, in markerInfoWindow function, set your marker to this and it will be fixed. 
marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true